# Retrofit не входит через Basic Auth в приложение Flask

Tags: android, flask, retrofit, retrofit2

Я сделал API в своем приложении Flask. По адресу `seriousblog.herokuapp.com/api/token` нужно аутентифицироваться с помощью Basic Auth, чтобы получить токен.

Я спокойно получаю токен через HTTPie:

```
http --auth "Роберт Дауни младший":"password" POST seriousblog.herokuapp.com/api/token
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 50
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 27 Jun 2019 13:41:12 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.15.4 Python/3.7.3

{
    "token": "blah-blah-blah"
}
```

Но через Retrofit не могу это сделать.

**Код Android-приложения:**
При нажатии на кнопку *show* должен выводится токен (класс Token), но токен равен null

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView log;
    Button show; // при нажатии на эту кнопку должен выводится токен

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        log = findViewById(R.id.log);
        show = findViewById(R.id.show);

        show.setOnClickListener(this);

        FakeDb.login(((MyApp)getApplicationContext())); // здесь происходит логин
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case(R.id.show):
                showToken();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void append(String s){
        log.append(s+"\n");
    }

    private void showToken(){
        append("Токен: "+FakeDb.getToken());
        append("= = = = = = = = = =\n");
    }
}
```

*SeriousblogAPI.java*

```
public interface SeriousBlogAPI {

    @GET("users/{id}/posts")
    Call<List<Post>> getPosts(@Path("id") int id, @Header("Authorization") String token);

    @POST("users/post")
    Call<Post> createPost(@Body BodyData body, @Header("Authorization") String token);

    @POST("token")
    Call<Token> getToken(@Header("Authorization") String credentials);

}
```

*MyApp.java*

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private SeriousBlogAPI api;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://seriousblog.herokuapp.com/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        api = retrofit.create(SeriousBlogAPI.class);
    }

    public SeriousBlogAPI getApi() {
        return api;
    }

}
```

*FakeDb.java*

```
public class FakeDb {

    private static String USERNAME = "Роберт Дауни младший";
    private static String PASSWORD = "password";
    private static Token token;

    public static void login(MyApp app){
        SeriousBlogAPI api = app.getApi();
        Call<Token> callToken = api.getToken(Credentials.basic(USERNAME, PASSWORD));
        callToken.enqueue(new Callback<Token>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Token> call, Response<Token> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    token = response.body();
                } else {
                    try {
                        Log.e("stag", response.errorBody().string());
                    } catch(IOException e){
                        Log.e("stag", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Token> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("stag", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public static String getToken(){
        return token.token;
    }

}
```

*Token.java*

```
public class Token {

    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    public String token;

}
```

В логах вот это:

```
2019-06-27 18:57:50.513 13346-13346/com.example.httpclientstesting E/stag: {"error":"Unauthorized"}
```

Также и через Postman выводит это:

```
{
    "error": "Unauthorized"
}
```

Вот код API, если нужно(все файлы находятся в пакете api):

*init.py*

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)

from app.api import users, errors, tokens
```

*users.py*

```
from app.api import bp
from app.models import User, Post
from app import db
from flask import jsonify, request, url_for, g

from app.api.errors import bad_request
from app.api.auth import token_auth

@bp.route('/users/<int:id>/posts', methods=["GET"])
@token_auth.login_required
def get_posts(id):
    user = User.query.get_or_404(id)
    posts = Post.to_collection(user.posts)
    return jsonify(posts)

@bp.route("/users/post", methods=["POST"])
@token_auth.login_required
def create_post():
    data = request.get_json() or {}
    if 'body' not in data:
        return bad_request("must include body")
    post = Post(body=data['body'], author=g.current_user)
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(post.to_dict())
```

*tokens.py*

```
from flask import jsonify, g
from app import db
from app.api import bp
from app.api.auth import basic_auth, token_auth

@bp.route('/token', methods=["POST"])
@basic_auth.login_required
def get_token():
    token = g.current_user.get_token()
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'token': token})

@bp.route('/token', methods=["DELETE"])
@token_auth.login_required
def revoke_token():
    g.current_user.revoke_token()
    db.session.commit()
    return '', 204
```

*auth.py*

```
basic_auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
token_auth = HTTPTokenAuth()

@basic_auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if user is None:
        return False
    g.current_user = user
    return user.check_password(password)

@basic_auth.error_handler
def basic_auth_error():
    return error_response(401)

@token_auth.verify_token
def verify_token(token):
    g.current_user = User.check_token(token) if token else None
    return g.current_user is not None

@token_auth.error_handler
def token_auth_error():
    return error_response(401)
```

*errors.py*

```
from flask import jsonify
from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES

# for 400 error
def bad_request(message):
    return error_response(400, message)

def error_response(status_code, message=None):
    payload = {
        'error': HTTP_STATUS_CODES.get(status_code, 'Unknown error')
    }
    if message:
        payload['message'] = message
    response = jsonify(payload)
    response.status_code = status_code
    return response
```

**В чем может быть проблема?** Почему при входе через HTTPie все хорошо, а через Retrofit (а также Postman) появляются проблемы?

Comment: Мне не знакома нотация описывания запроса для HTTPie, засим просто погадаю. Если под `--auth` имеется в виду заголовок `Authorization`, то, быть может, там имеется в виду не хэшированное значение для передачи. Т.е. попробуйте вместо `Credentials.basic(USERNAME, PASSWORD)` передать просто `USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD` или `"Basic " + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодарю [ЮрийСПб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17609/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%A1%D0%9F%D0%B1) и [Alexander Fokin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/277874/alexander-fokin) за помощь! Разобрался и получилось такое решение:

*FakeDb.java*

```
private static String encode(String s){
    String ss = Base64.encodeToString(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    return ss;
}

public static void login(MyApp app){
        SeriousBlogAPI api = app.getApi();
        Call<Token> callToken = api.getToken("Basic "+encode(USERNAME+":"+PASSWORD));
        ...
}
```

В итоге логин происходит правильно и работает так как надо.

Answer (score 1):

У вас какая-то каша получается. Basic Auth подразумевает под собой работу без токена. Просто в каждый запрос добавляется header вида

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
```

И токен вам не нужен в этом случае. "QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l" - это закодированная в Base64 строка {LOGIN}:{PASSWORD}.

P.S. Рекомендую вам подключить к Retrofit [вот это](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor), чтобы видеть все запросы и ответы.

Comment: "У вас какая-то каша получается.": такую реализацию я взял из [этого урока](https://habr.com/ru/post/358152/). Как я понял, суть в том, что токен берется через Basic Auth, и этот токен используется во всех других маршрутах API, то есть нет такого, что имя пользователя и пароль нужно вводить для авторизации у каждого маршрута API, а вместо этого для авторизации используется токен.